# Webpack 2 won't work when using ts-loader

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, webpack-2

I have been setting up a basic angular 2 (typescript) application, which uses Webpack 2 for bundling etc.

My issue is that when I use ts-loader to process typescript (.ts) files I get a lot of errors. I suspect, but am not totally sure, that the errors are to do with ts-loader **not** excluding the node_modules directory even though I specify for it to exclude it in the webpack config.

I just want to be able to setup my webpack config (and my app) so that typescript can be transpiled and the app can be correctly bundled with webpack. Please help.

**Webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.ts',
    output: {
    filename: './dist/bundle.js',
},
resolve: {
    // Add `.ts` and `.tsx` as a resolvable extension.
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'] // note if using webpack 1 you'd also need a '' in the array as well
},
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'ts-loader'
    }]
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
        /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
    __dirname
),
]
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "tiptip-webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack -d --watch"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.6",
    "@angularclass/conventions-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "~1.2.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "~3.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.9",
    "rxjs": "5.0.2",
    "zone.js": "0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "ts-loader": "^2.0.3",
    "typescript": "^2.2.0",
    "typings": "^2.1.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

**Error messages after running 'npm run build'**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a webpack problem but a TypeScript problem. Webpack correctly ignores the `node_modules` but TypeScript complains because it doesn't know the types for `Map` or `Set`. These are ES6 features and if you set the `target` in your `compilerOptions` to `es5` it won't include these in the compilation and therefore doesn't know their types. From the [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) documentation:

> Note: If `--lib` is not specified a default library is injected. The default library injected is:
>   ► For --target ES5: DOM,ES5,ScriptHost
>   ► For --target ES6: DOM,ES6,DOM.Iterable,ScriptHost

You can set the `lib` option to use `es6` (or any higher version e.g. `es2017`):

```
"lib": ["es6", "dom"]
```

Comment: This is great. I wish they made the Webpack 2 documentation a little bit more clear (and detailed).